# Setting cookie in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I've been tinkering on this and can't seem to spot the problem. I'm able to get the state right but it's not saving in the cookie.

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_setBgSoundCookie', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_setBgSoundCookie', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
function so_wp_ajax_function(){
    $state  =  $_POST['state'];
    setcookie("bg_sound", $state ,time()+60*60*24); //expires in 24 hours
    wp_die();
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
function setSoundCookie(state){

    $.ajax({
        url: vision_globals.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action :'setBgSoundCookie',
            state : state
            },
        success: function (data) {

            },
        error: function (er) {
            console.log(er);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `return $bgsstate;`...I don't believe `$bgsstate` is defined here...

Comment: I removed it in my latest version, thanks for pointing it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the cookie path:

```
setcookie('visionare_sound', $state, time()+60*60*24, '/');
```

The cookie is being set...but likely not to your intended path.

Comment: aha! yes, you're right. it works like a charm. Thank you!